# How do I make reactive global property in vuejs plugin?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-reactivity

I put $testCounter in a plugin to make it global :

```
Vue.use({
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$testCounter = 0;
    Vue.prototype.$incrementCounter = () => {
      Vue.prototype.$testCounter++;
    };
});
```

I want to output it in some component. I also need its value to be updated globally, and reactively :

```
<template>
  <p>{{ $testCounter }}</p>
</template>

<script>
  mounted() {
    let comp = this;
    comp.watcherId = setInterval(() => {
      comp.$incrementCounter();

      // I want to remove this line and still be reactive :
      comp.$forceUpdate();

    }, 1000);
  }
</script>
```

I need the property to be reactive, I tried a multiple solution as watchers, computed props, vm.$set(...), but I can't find the right way to do this.

Comment: you could use Vuex ?

Comment: I'm not planning using it for now, I avoid installing too many layers for basic apps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution 1**: use Vuex

**Solution 2**: set the global reactive data in root component and use it by calling `this.$root`

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/mdt4673d/2/

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <test1>
      {{$root.testCounter}}

  </test1>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
Vue.component('test1', {
    template: `
  <div>
  test1
  <slot></slot>
  </div>
  `,
    mounted() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.$root.incrementCounter();
        }, 1000)
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        testCounter: 1
    },
    methods: {
        incrementCounter: function() {
            this.testCounter++;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: the example you have provided does not define global props on a prototype but on the data of the app itself. this is an entirely different case. global props defined on the prototype are indeed not reactive.

Comment: Vuex for the win